# Powershell ParameterSet error when two or more parameters are used

Tags: powershell

I have a script that prints out log information, basically text. The script has 3 parameters: 'ID', 'Text' and 'Day', where I could filter the information based on those parameters. It's like this:

```
function Get-Log{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="All")] 
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName="ByID"
        )]
        [Int]$ID,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName="ByText"
        )]
        [String]$Text,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName="ByDay"
        )]
        [String]$Day
    )
    ...
}
```

It works fine if I call the function with no or only one parameter, Ex.:

```
Get-Log
Get-Log -Text "sample"
```

But when I use two or more parameters, like:

```
Get-Log -Text "sample" -Day "29/04/2016"
```

It spills out parameter set error:

```
Get-Log : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters
+ get-log -Text "sample" -Day "29/04/2016"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Change], ParameterBind
   ingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Get-Change
```

Is there a way to specify a different parameter set used when 2 or more parameters are specified? Or maybe a better way to do that?

Comment: Why do you use parameter sets in the first place?

Comment: Because I thought it would be easier to manage the query possibilites with the switch statement, like `Switch($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName){"ByID" {query1} "ByText" {query2}}`, but I think I might be using if's anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The way I use parameter sets is to define one "mode" of the script along with the parameters that "mode" would have.

Example, the RunOnce param set has two mandatory parameters, Server and Date.

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="RunOnce",
  HelpMessage="Enter ServerName to schedule reboot for.")]
 [switch]$RunOnce,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunOnce")]
 [string]$server,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunOnce")]
 [string]$date,
```

Used as such `Function -RunOnce -Server "blah" -Date "04/29/2016 18:20"`